# TextView ActionMode Can't Show SubMenu Properly

Tags: android, menu, android-actionmode

I wrote a custom menu for an `ActionMode` and passed it to the `TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(ActionMode)` as a custom `ActionMode` in text selecting process. It works but when I'm clicking on the Items with `SubMenu` , it shows them just for a second and then `ActionMode` close and do not let me to select a submenu item. It also happens when I'm using Overflow item when I'm using `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM` for my itmes.
any Idea?
I'm using Android ICS

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Action Mode is closed/finished when the `EditText` lost its focus:

**[`TextView.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L7904)**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);

    if (mEditor != null) mEditor.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);

    startStopMarquee(hasWindowFocus);
}
```

Note: `EditText` is subclass of `TextView`.

**[`Editor.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L1055)**

```
void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    if (hasWindowFocus) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
        hideControllers();
        ...
    }
}
```

**Solution**

I tried to create this:

```
package com.edwardsp.sample.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        if (hasWindowFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        }
    }
}
```

and use the `CustomEditText` as normal `EditText`. The action mode submenu can be shown. I didn't find strange behavior in `CustomEditText`. If someone finds strange behavior from this implementation, please let me know.